# metaio sdk (openGL) brakes font and image rendering

Tags: android, text, fonts, render, augmented-reality

I have 2 activities, activity A in which I have a lot of info displayed (textviews and images) and activity B which is started from activity A, activity B is the [Hello Augmented World](http://docs.metaio.com/bin/view/Main/HelloAugmentedWorldExample) tutorial activity where I use the augmented reality engine from metaio. The problem appears when closing activity B and resuming to activity A, most of the fonts(characters) are rendered as blocks and the images are all black. This only occurs when resuming activity A after killing activity B. I found a similar [post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/117173-Font-rendering-problem-on-Android-only-GUI.Label%28%29) but it doesn't help me at all. I can't figure out what the problem is, and where to start debugging. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, the augmented reality activity called a method(`setTexture`) from the wrong thread (`not OpenGL thread`) and that was causing something to crash the rendering pipeline.